# Owl carusel / How to change theme

Tags: jquery, html, css, carousel, owl-carousel

I am trying to implement owl carousel into my website. [OWL CAROUSEL](http://www.owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/). It is working great, but only with "custom" theme. I need to implement the "One slide" theme. These examples are shown in "Mor demos" section on that website. Can you please tell me if I do have to downpload that theme from somewhere, or how can I use the one slide theme? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the theme is built in. To use it, you need to include the `singleItem` parameter in the initialization:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({

  navigation : true, // Show next and prev buttons
  slideSpeed : 300,
  paginationSpeed : 400,
  singleItem:true

  });

});
```

The site also includes this CSS which appears to make the images fill the container:

```
#owl-demo .item img{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Comment: thanx. I will accept your answer. Is there a way to automate the carousel? For example to change the image every 2 seconds?

Comment: @MartinNemeth It looks like you can use the play event `owl.trigger('owl.play', interval);`, so `$("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({...options}).trigger('owl.play', 2000);`